# Give random list objects attributes, python 3

Tags: list

I am very new to programming. I have an assignment to design a game similar to minesweeper. So here's what I'm thinking right now on how to make the gameplan with hidden mines. First of all, I create a list which will be printed for the user to see (createPlan is the function which creates the plan, and showPlan is the function who shows the plan). Second, I'm thinking of creating another list which is identical to skapaPlan. However using methods to apply different attributes to the list object. For example,I want to apply a mine to list object nr x. How do I do that and still keep them "connected"? Thanks!

```
class Square:
    def __init__(mine = False, empty = 0):
        self.mina = mine
    ....

def createPlan(size, sign):
    spelplan = []
    for i in range(size):
        gameplan.append([sign]*size)
    return gameplan

def square_attribut(gameplan):
    gomdplan = spelplan

    (help)

def showPlan(gameplan):
  i = 0
  bracket = list(range(0,len(gameplan)))
  rownr = [" "] + bracket
  for row in [bracket]+gameplan:
    print(rownr[i],end = " ")
    i += 1
    for square in row:
      print(square,end = " ")
    print()
```

Comment: You seem to be asking how to manage state in object oriented programming. That is an awfully broad question. Would you care to focus it?

Comment: Okey I see your point. The list a , a = [1,2,3,4], is the list which the user sees when playing. The list b, b = [1,2,mine,4], is the list which the user is "really" playing through. On the display, all they see is 1 2 3 4. But let us say that 3 = mine. So when they choose 3, they lose the game.